Problem Using Selenium for Chrome to find element in HTML file with C#
I am using Selenium to find elements in HTML document displayed within the Chrome browser.  The HTML is not of my making and seems to have lots of problems.  I have no ability to change its generation, I just have to work with what I have.
Here is a snippet of the HTML for an element I am trying to find from its text ">General Lease Legal Information"
<div class="TableTitlebar HeaderedTableTitlebar">
<div class="FastTitlebar">
<div class="FastTitlebarCaptionWrapper">
<h3 id="caption2_Dd-53" class=" FastTitlebarCaption">General Lease Legal Information</h3>
</div>

This is many levels deep in a very messy construct.  I have tried different combinations of search criteria for FindElement.  I always get the element not found error.
The big problem is that the website that is generating this HTML will regenerate the IDs of elements every so often when a page is freshly rendered.  So using a search on ID will eventually break.  Also attributes like class names are just repeats of the IDs and does not give any stable rendering of what the element is about.
Here is how to get to the webpage.
Open a browser and go to:
https://oktap.tax.ok.gov/OkTAP/web?link=PUBLICPUNLKP
Select the radio button for "Search By PUN:"
Enter the value "029-123551-0-0000"
Scroll to the bottom of the page and select the "Search" button.
Just above the Search button will be a line of text with "029-123551-0-0000" highlighted on the far left.  Select this link.
On the new page, select the "Printable" tab on the right side of the menu bar.
On the new page, scroll down to find the table for General Lease Legal Information.
As the annotation in the HTML is so poor, the only way to find the following table element, that contains the data I seek, without hardcoding an ID to search for the header text in the HTML snippet I posted, then search for the first table element after this.
This is truly a mess.  I am not sure the website is scrapable due to the poor construction of the HTML.  I am using C# as that is the proficiency level of myself and the other programmers in my company.  I am open to suggestions for how to find the desired element, along with reengineering the whole application.

I'm not sure what the issue is... there are a LOT of IDs on that page and they are consistent (not random each page load, etc.).
The code below works according to the steps you provided and prints all cells in the "General Lease Legal Information" table. It does not use any IDs since you said that was a problem.
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
string url = "https://oktap.tax.ok.gov/OkTAP/web?link=PUBLICPUNLKP";
driver.Url = url;

string pun = "029-123551-0-0000";

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("caption2_Dd-5"))); // wait for element on page to make sure page is loaded
ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> inputs = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//tr[.//span[text()='Search By PUN:']]//input"));
inputs.ElementAt(0).Click(); // Search By PUN radio button
inputs.ElementAt(1).SendKeys(pun); // Search By PUN field
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[text()='Search']")).Click(); // Search button
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//table[@data-delmsg][.//a[text()='PUN']]//td//a"))).Click(); // Click first result link
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//span[text()='Printable']"))).Click(); // Click "Printable" tab

IWebElement table = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class,'TableContainer')][.//h3[text()='General Lease Legal Information']]//table[contains(@class,'DocTableNormal')]")));
string headers = string.Join(",", table.FindElements(By.CssSelector("th")).Select(e => e.Text).ToArray());
Console.WriteLine(headers); // write headers

ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> cells = table.FindElements(By.CssSelector("td"));
string cellText = string.Join(",", cells.Select(e => e.Text).ToArray());
Console.WriteLine(cellText); // write cells

Output
Q4,Q3,Q2,Q1,Section,Township,Range
,,,AL,36,01N,09E

You can write that to a CSV and open it as an Excel sheet or whatever you need.

You can remove the row in rows loop if there's only ever a single row in that table. I wasn't sure so to be safe I added the loop.

"The big problem is that the website that is generating this HTML will regenerate the IDs of elements every so often when a page is freshly rendered." I would imagine its cached

@mattsharp I ran my code over 10 times and never saw the IDs change... I dunno.

@mattsharp I added a version that doesn't use any IDs, if you are interested.

You would imagine its cached to <1h so maybe you're right or maybe they update it on deploy (ids regenerated) or something. Regardless your code looks like it should work

The IDs don't change every time the page is reloaded.  But there is something about the server side generation of the HTML that when, I am guessing, an adjustment is made in the logic generating the HTML, then there can be one or more changes in the IDs.  This makes the scraping a moving target.

@BartAtRanch Understood. I updated the code to not use any IDs and it's working just fine. Did you try it?

Thanks for the sample code.  The use of "wait" might help.  But even in your "non-ID" code you are subject to changes in IDs.  The values like "caption2_Dd-5" will change when there is a change in the IDs of connected elements.  Also, the different sections in the HTML are so identical, without any unique explanation of what the use of the element, that style types or classes are repeated so that doing a search could retrieve any one of the associated elements, not the one you want.

Then an additional question as to how Selenium parses the HTML.  From behavior, and the workflow logic in the code I was initially given by the original author, it looks like when Selenium does a FindElement, that it moves the starting pointer for the next find to the position of the last successful find.  I can work with this if this is the case.  I will just have to be rigorous in how I walk down the HTML structure.  But what happens to the search start pointer if the requested element is not found?

Are the Selenium calls, like FindElement, synchronous or asynchronous as far as returning control to the calling program vs. the actions on the target webpage is completed.  I am guessing asynchronous if there is a need for wait.  Just want to make sure I understand how the driver functions.

The code is not subject to changes in IDs if I don't use any IDs to locate elements. Have you tried running it? Did it work?

I don't understand your second comment. All Selenium code is synchronous... the code execution blocks on each step. Waits are needed because of the variations in page loading times, etc.

I am trying out your code.  Works great.  You do this;
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("caption2_Dd-5"))); // wait for element on page to make sure page is loaded
Because of the change in IDs when the HTML is regenerated, what was initially "Caption2_Dd-5" when the code was written could be changed to "Caption2_Dd-8". This has has happened before and I am sure it will happen again.  I got around this by instead of using the PUN entry elements as the "wait till visible" search target.

I have removed the first code block that contains IDs. Use the code block that is remaining... it should work with no issues and no ongoing maintenance needed.

Sure... I meant to go back and find a new target for that check that didn't use an ID. I had a hard time using waits with many of the elements with IDs for some reason so I just picked an element on the page to ensure the page was loaded and ran with it.

Jeff -- if you would consider a little consulting work, email: bart@sweetwaterdata.com

@BartAtRanch Just sent you an email.
